Custom Dropdown/Selectize Field Type
This is a question in Craft 5.
I want to create a field type to pull in all of the Sections and display them in a Dropdown/Selectize Field.
I've got that showing ok with this:
protected function inputHtml(mixed $value, ?ElementInterface $element, bool $inline): string
  {
    $options = array_map(function($section) {
      return ['label' => $section->name, 'value' => $section->handle];
    }, Craft::$app->entries->getAllSections());

    return Cp::selectizeHtml([
      'id' => $this->getInputId(),
      'describedBy' => $this->describedBy,
      'name' => $this->handle,
      'value' => $value,
      'options' => $options,
      'disabled' => false,
    ]);
  }

When I save an Entry with a Section selected, I get the error Invalid entry type ID: 4. Presumably, it thinks I'm trying to change the Section of the Entry? All I want to do is save the handle, so I can then use it on the front-end.
I'm guessing it's to do with normalizeValue:
public function normalizeValue(mixed $value, ?ElementInterface $element): mixed
{
  return $value;
}

But I'm not really sure what to do with that.
Use case is because I want to allow authors to select a Section and show all of the Entries on the front-end.
